# How to import existing JSON file into Isar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

Hi I am new to Isar Flutter. I want to know is there any way to import existing JSON file into Isar? 
 I try to search this on the Internet but can't find much on it. 
Below is the structure of my Json file.

```
{
 "food": [
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "Cake",
        "description": [
            {
                "type": "Chocolate",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "fruits",
                "quantity": 3
            },
            {
                "type": "Corn",
                "quantity": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "name": "Raised",
        "description": [
            {
                "type": "Grape",
                "quantity": 6
            },
            {
                "type": "Wheat",
                "quantity": 2
            }
        ]
    }
],
"instruction": [
      {
        "category": "instruction_1002",
        "content": "abc1234"
      },
      {
        "category": "instruction_1003",
        "content": "def56789"
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's set the above existing json data to a constants.dart

```
const response = {
  "food": [
    {
      "id": "0001",
      "name": "Cake",
      "description": [
        {"id": "instruction_1002", "type": "Chocolate"},
        {"id": "instruction_1003", "type": "fruits"},
        {"id": "instruction_1004", "type": "Corn"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "0002",
      "name": "Raised",
      "description": [
        {"id": "instruction_2002", "type": "Grape"},
        {"id": "instruction_2003", "type": "Wheat"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "instruction": [
    {"category": "instruction_1002", "content": "abc1234"},
    {"category": "instruction_1003", "content": "def56789"}
  ]
};
```

From this data we'll get to create 3 collections and one of them will be an embedded object

Create a folder called collections.

Inside the collections folder create a dart file called food.dart

This file will contain a collection called Food and another collection called Description that will be embedded to the Food collection. The properties are also defined by the keys provided in the existing json data in constants.dart

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'food.g.dart';

@Collection()
class Food {
  Food({this.foodId, this.name, this.description});

  Id? foodId = Isar.autoIncrement;
  String? id;
  String? name;
  List<Description>? description;
}

@embedded
class Description {
  Description({this.id, this.type});

  String? id;
  String? type;
}
```

Inside the collections folder create another dart file called instruction.dart

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'instruction.g.dart';

@Collection()
class Instruction {
  Instruction({this.category, this.content});

  Id? id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  String? category;
  String? content;
}
```

Next, we need to create generated files for these two files by using build_runner.

Import the build_runner flutter package.

Run the command below to generate the files:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

You'll find 2 files created in the collections folder: food.g.dart & instruction.g.dart

Next, we'll go to the necessary class, to import the existing json data to isar database. In my case I'll use the skeleton below to proceed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Isar isar;
  const MyApp({super(key: key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Isar Database"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
               //IMPORT LOGIC HERE
              },
              child: const Text("Import JSON"),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  
}
```

Now let's add the import json logic.

Ensure you have these packages installed.

```
  isar: ^3.0.5
  isar_generator: ^3.0.5
  isar_flutter_libs: ^3.0.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.13
```

Let's initialize isar to the application in the main function. It will look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/collections/food.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/collections/instruction.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/constant.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  //INITIALIZE ISAR TO THE APPLICATION
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  if (dir.existsSync()) {
    final isar = await Isar.open([FoodSchema, InstructionSchema]);

    runApp(MyApp(isar: isar));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Isar isar;
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.isar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Isar Database"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //IMPORT LOGIC HERE
              },
              child: const Text("Import JSON"),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Now, we create a function that will use the importJson() method by Isar database as shown below.

```
importjson() async {
    //We first clear the database - not a must!
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.clear();
    });
   
    importFood(); //This function imports the data in the key 'food' from the existing json data

    importInstructions(); //This function imports the data in the key 'instruction' from the existing json data
  }

  importFood() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.foods.importJson(response['food']!);
    });
  }

  importInstructions() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.instructions.importJson(response['instruction']!);
    });
  }
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/collections/food.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/collections/instruction.dart';
import 'package:import_to_isar/constant.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  if (dir.existsSync()) {
    final isar = await Isar.open([FoodSchema, InstructionSchema]);

    runApp(MyApp(isar: isar));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Isar isar;
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.isar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Isar Database"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                importjson();
              },
              child: const Text("Import JSON"),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  importjson() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.clear();
    });

    importFood();
    importInstructions();
  }

  importFood() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.foods.importJson(response['food']!);
    });
  }

  importInstructions() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.instructions.importJson(response['instruction']!);
    });
  }
}
```

The UI looks like this:

[image]

To view the data in the Isar database, use the Isar Inspector. You'll find the link on the terminal of your IDE when you run the application.

This is how my Isar Inspector looks like:

[image]

[image]

To display the information stored in the 2 collections respectively,
let's:

1. Change MyApp class to a State class.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Isar isar;
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.isar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Isar Database"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      importjson();
                    },
                    child: const Text("Import JSON"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  importjson() async {
    await widget.isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await widget.isar.clear();
    });

    importFood();
    importInstructions();
  }

  importFood() async {
    await widget.isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await widget.isar.foods.importJson(response['food']!);
    });
  }

  importInstructions() async {
    await widget.isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await widget.isar.instructions.importJson(response['instruction']!);
    });
  }
}
```

2. Create a new function called exportjson() that will get data from Food collection.

```
 Future<List<Food>> exportjson() async {
    return await widget.isar.foods.where().findAll();
  }
```

3. In the design, we'll add a Text to refer to Exported JSON and a FutureBuilder that will help us handle the data that has been collected using exportjson() function

```
const Text(
    "Exported JSON",
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
  FutureBuilder<List<Food>>(
      future: exportjson(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<Food> foodlist = snapshot.data ?? [];

        if (foodlist.isNotEmpty) {
          return Column(
            children: [],
          );
        } else {
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        }
      })
```

4. Let's build the childrens attribute for Column with what we have received from snapsot.data. We'll create the function below with argument of type List:

```
List<Widget> buildWidget(List<Food> f) {
    List<Widget> x = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
     
      x.add(SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(f[i].name ?? ""),
              const Text(
                "Description",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
    return x;
  }
```

5. Let's pass this function to the childrens attribute as shown below:

```
 FutureBuilder<List<Food>>(
                    future: exportjson(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      List<Food> foodlist = snapshot.data ?? [];

                      if (foodlist.isNotEmpty) {
                        return Column(
                          children: buildWidget(foodlist),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const SizedBox.shrink();
                      }
                    })
```

The display will look like this:
[image]

6. Now, let's display description of each food using Instruction collection by creating another function that will query checking where category equals to the id of the description for the food, and then build the widgets for us.

```
Future<List<Widget>> buildDescription(List<Description> d) async {
    List<Widget> y = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      Instruction? x = await widget.isar.instructions
          .where()
          .filter()
          .categoryEqualTo(d[i].id)
          .findFirst();
      String content = x?.content ?? "";
      y.add(ListTile(
        leading: Text(
          d[i].type!,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        trailing: Text(content),
      ));
    }
    return y;
  }
```

7. We'll pass this function in the buildWidget() function like shown:

```
 List<Widget> buildWidget(List<Food> f) {
    List<Widget> x = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
      List<Description> description = f[i].description ?? [];
      x.add(SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(f[i].name ?? ""),
              const Text(
                "Description",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: buildDescription(description),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    List<Widget> c = snapshot.data ?? [];
                    return Column(children: c);
                  })
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
    return x;
  }
```

Now the screen will look as shown displaying description information of each food.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. May I know In flutter list view how do I query and display a list of "description" that belong to food name "Cake"?

Comment: Hi @JovenDev , since the answer to that is more detailed, I'll edit my answer above with additional information based on your question. Please upvote me once it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mobterest Studio, for No.6 if I don't want to involve Instruction collection when display a list of Description under each Food, is it possible? example widget.isar.foods.description...does it work on embedded object? I have modified my sample json in the question, can you have a look

Comment: Hi @JovenDev , if you don't want to involve the instruction collection that's ok. Just comment out the "Instruction x"  variable that is created and remain with the leading attribute of the ListTile that displays description.

Comment: Hi @Mobterest Studio, i'm following your youtube tutorial, is very helpful. Will you do more lessons on Isar? currently Isar4 is released. Hope there is lesson on encryption, isar + riverpod. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JovenDev, thank you so much. I have received requests on this. I'm planning on investing time on it and share as much as I can. I'll also consider the suggestions you have shared. Appreciate the support!